# UITableView within a UITableViewCell events missing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I've implemented a `UITableView` containing a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UITableView` inside, I'm able to bind all my data properly but what I'm missing are the events not being fired inside my inner `UITableViews`.

**Basically:**

```
outer UITableView
----custom cell
---- ---- ----inner UITableView #1
---- ---- ---- ----custom cell with two rows, row#1 with labels
---- ---- ---- ----custom cell with two rows, row#2 with swipe gesture
----custom cell
---- ---- ----inner UITableView #2
---- ---- ---- ----custom cell with two rows, row#1 with labels
---- ---- ---- ----custom cell with two rows, row#2 with swipe gesture
----custom cell
---- ---- ----inner UITableView #3
---- ---- ---- ----custom cell with two rows, row#1 with labels
---- ---- ---- ----custom cell with two rows, row#2 with swipe gesture
```

etc...

The swipe gesture inside the inner `UITableView` is not fired, no event is fired actually. I've tried overriding the touch events but they are not hit. I've tried numerous things to no avail including calling the NextResponder touch events.

The view containing the outer `UITableView` is scrollable, maybe that has something to do with it?

What I want to achieve is that only row #2 gets swiped and not the entire inner `UITableView` (it works when done from the outer `UITableView` but it is not the requirement since both rows #1 and #2 swipe) but since the events are not passed down, I can't get it to work.

What am I missing?

This is how I define the inner `UITableView` inside the outer `UITableView` custom cell:

```
public PlanningGwWrapperCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
    _playersTable = new PlanningPlayersTableView();
    _playersTableSource = new MvxPlanningGwPlayersTableViewSource(_playersTable);

    _layout = CreateLayout();

    _playersTable.Source = _playersTableSource;
    _playersTable.Delegate = new PlanningGwPlayersTableDelegate();

    ContentView.AddSubview(new UILayoutHost(_layout));

    InitializeBindings();

    _playersTable.ReloadData();
}
```

The _layout is a LinearLayout (XibFree).

The UITableView is simply this:

```
class PlanningPlayersTableView : UITableView
{
    public PlanningPlayersTableView()
    {
        PrepareTable();
    }

    void PrepareTable()
    {
        SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        RowHeight = Dimens.TableRowHeight;
        ScrollEnabled = false;
        BackgroundColor = Colors.AppBackground;
    }
}
```

The table source is:

```
public class MvxPlanningGwPlayersTableViewSource : BaseMvxTableViewSource<PlanningGwPlayersCell>
{
    public MvxPlanningGwPlayersTableViewSource(UITableView tableView)
        : base(tableView)
    {
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var source = (MvxPlanningGwPlayersTableViewSource)tableView.Source;
        var itemsSource = (source).ItemsSource;

        if (itemsSource == null) return false;

        var row = ((ObservableCollection<PlanningGWItemsViewModel>)itemsSource)[indexPath.Row];

        return row.CanAdd || row.CanRemove;
    }

    public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        switch (editingStyle)
        {
            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
                break;
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCellEditingStyle EditingStyleForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        return (PlanningGwPlayersCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(PlanningGwPlayersCell.Id);
    }
}
```

So any clues on how to pass down the events? Can the outer table respond only to the scroll event while all other events get handled by the inner table?

**UPDATE**
Turns out the problem has to do with the following line:

```
ContentView.AddSubview(new UILayoutHost(_layout));
```

The UILayoutHost is swallowing the events, if I place the table directly inside as a sub view, the events are kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was indeed splitting the header row (first row) and swipe row (second row) from the UILayoutHost:

```
public PlanningGwWrapperCell(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        ...

        ContentView.AddSubview(new UILayoutHost(_header));
        ContentView.AddSubview(_playersTable);

        InitializeBindings();

        _playersTable.ReloadData();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        _playersTable.Frame = new CGRect(0, Dimens.TableRowHeight, ContentView.Bounds.Width, Dimens.TableRowHeight);
        _header.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParameters(ContentView.Bounds.Width, Dimens.TableRowHeight);
    }
```